# How to model a star tracker measurement in quaternions

Tags: rotational-kinematics

I'm trying to design an attitude determination system for a cubesat using an extended kalman filter.

To implement the kalman filter I need to model the measurement from a star tracker which outputs an estimated quaternion.

Currently I am doing q_measured = q_true + randn * sigma_star_tracker^2

I'm not sure if this is maintaining the unity constraint?

Is there a better way to model a quaternion with zero mean measurement noise?

Answer (score 0):

Quaternions that stand for orientations or rotations are always unit quaternions, or members of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. They are always quaternions of the form:

$$q = \exp(q_x\,\mathbf{i} + q_y\,\mathbf{j}+q_z\,\mathbf{k})\tag{1}$$

Accordingly, the naïve model that simply adds noise through an equation like $q_m = q + X\,\sigma^2$, where $X$ is a unit magnitude random quaternion, will not work because the resulting $q_m$ will not be a unit quaternion.

There are several ways around this dilemma. You will need to experiment with them to check which will work for you.

The first uses your naïve equation and then finds  nearest unit quaternion by simply normalizing the result. This however, will color the noise sequence slightly in ways you may not be happy with.

The second simply represents unit quaternions as logarithms in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ of purely imaginary quaternions. Thus, we give the unit quaternion in (1) the co-ordinates $(q_x,\,q_y,\,q_z)$. We peturb these by our random variables to get:

$$(q_x^\prime,\,q_y^\prime,\,q_z^\prime) = (q_x + \sigma^2\,X,\,q_y + \sigma^2\,Y,\,q_z + \sigma^2\,Z)$$

where $X,\,Y,\,Z$ are unit variance, zero mean random variables, then our perturbed unit quaternion is simply:

$$q^\prime = \exp(q_x^\prime\,\mathbf{i}+q_y^\prime\,\mathbf{j}+q_z^\prime\,\mathbf{k}) = \cos\left(\sqrt{{q_x^\prime}^2+{q_y^\prime}^2+{q_z^\prime}^2}\right) + \frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{{q_x^\prime}^2+{q_y^\prime}^2+{q_z^\prime}^2}\right)}{\sqrt{{q_x^\prime}^2+{q_y^\prime}^2+{q_z^\prime}^2}}\left(q_x^\prime\,\mathbf{i}+q_y^\prime\,\mathbf{j}+q_z^\prime\,\mathbf{k}\right)$$